# nginx not finding some JS files

Tags: nginx

```
server {
 listen       80;
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/dashboards.access.log;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/dashboards-reg.error.log;
 root /usr/share/nginx/htmlresource;


         location /performance-platform/landlord-reg {
                  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_pass http://landlord-reg/dashboard/landlord-reg/pages/;
                  proxy_redirect http://landlord-reg/dashboard/landlord-reg/pages/ $scheme://;
    }
        location ~* \.(jpg|ttf|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/landlord-reg/pages;
                  proxy_pass http://landlord-reg;


        }

         location /performance-platform/discharges {
                   root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/discharges/pages;
                  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_pass http://discharges/dashboard/discharges/pages/;
                  proxy_redirect http://discharges/dashboard/discharges/pages/ $scheme://;
          }
            location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/discharges/pages;
                  try_files /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/discharges/pages $uri;
                  proxy_pass http://discharges;

           }                       

}
```

The above is the more or less the full nginx config that is in sites-available.  the upstream servers are docker containers though that shouldn't really make any difference.

This finds all but 2 of my js files.

```
<script src="../resource/feedconf.js"></script>
```

This is NOT found ^^^

where as this is

```
<script src="../../../assets/js/widgets/errorWidget.js"></script>
```

I've tried 2 different approaches to achive the same thing one for landlord and one for discharges but neither work.  Ran out of ideas hence the question on here.

Comment: please share the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

On a initial look of the code I understand perhaps you meant to do the following. It would be better if you shared your folder hierarchy.

```
server {
     listen       80;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/dashboards.access.log;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/dashboards-reg.error.log;
     root /usr/share/nginx/htmlresource;


         location /performance-platform/landlord-reg {
                  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_pass http://landlord-reg/dashboard/landlord-reg/pages/;
                  proxy_redirect http://landlord-reg/dashboard/landlord-reg/pages/ $scheme://;

    } <-- delete this from here

        location ~* \.(jpg|ttf|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/landlord-reg/pages;
                  proxy_pass http://landlord-reg;


        } 

} <- add this here

         location /performance-platform/discharges {
                   root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/discharges/pages;
                  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_pass http://discharges/dashboard/discharges/pages/;
                  proxy_redirect http://discharges/dashboard/discharges/pages/ $scheme://;

          } <-- delete this from here

            location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboards/discharges/pages;
                  try_files /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/discharges/pages $uri;
                  proxy_pass http://discharges;
} <- add this here
           }
```

Comment: Directory structure is defined in the root directive.